# Push Notifications are displayed only if service worker is debugged

Tags: asp.net-mvc, google-chrome, push-notification, service-worker, web-push

I am trying to implement `web push notifications` in my `chrome browser` using a `.net MVC web application` and `service workers`.

I am able to subscribe to the push service and get the subscription object from web app.

But when try to send a notification message from the server, the notification doesn't get displayed.

But if I debug the service worker by placing a `break point` inside the `push event handler function`, the break point is hit and if I step through the code the push notification is displayed.

I am not sure where the problem lies. Please help.

Comment: Please add the code what you did tried.

Comment: Improved content formatting and added relevant tag

Comment: Pls provide your code otherwise your question does not make sense to us. Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

Finally found out what was causing the issue.

I subscribe from my local system, leave the browser open and send notification by connecting to a VM through MSRTC. The reason the notifications didn't get displayed was the MSRTC application was the active program and not my local system.

If I send notification from a different system, my browser receives and displays it.

Thanks for your replies.